# Linear Regression in R: factor or z-standardise dichotomous variables

Tags: r, regression, categorical-encoding

How should one handle dichotomous variables in a linear regression? Is it better to z-standardise or is it better to use factors?

For example I have data of an Experiment with a 2x2 Design in which further individual level variables (eg. attitude) were measured. The individual level variables are continous. The data looks the following:

```
#    id   dv   treat1   treat2   attitude
#     1   42        1        1        5.2
#     2   54        0        1        6.3
#     3   65        1        0        4.4
#     4   85        0        0        5.6
...

model_scale <- lm(dv ~ scale(attitude) * scale(treat1) * scale(treat2))
model_factor <- lm(dv ~ scale(attitude) * factor(treat1) * factor(treat2))
```

I suppose it depends on the interpretation. For categorial variables with more than two levels it is clear that using factor variables is the only option. For dichtomous variables it seems not as clear to me. Furthermore, how should one determine the reference level for factorial variables. I have noticed that even changing the reference level of a variable that is not significant, can change the estimate and p-value of a different variable (see last regression)

here is an example with the mtcars dataset:

```
mtcars$wt_s <- scale(mtcars$wt)

mtcars$am_s <- scale(mtcars$am)    
mtcars$am_f1 <- factor(mtcars$am, levels = c(1,0), labels = c("automatic", "manual"))
mtcars$am_f2 <- relevel(mtcars$am_F, ref = 2)

mtcars$vs_s <- scale(mtcars$vs)
mtcars$vs_f1 <- factor(mtcars$vs, levels = c(1,0), labels = c("straight", "V-shaped"))
mtcars$vs_f2 <- relevel(mtcars$vs_F, ref = 2)

summary(lm(mpg ~ wt_s * am_s * vs_s, data=mtcars))
summary(lm(mpg ~ wt_s * am_f1 * vs_f1, data=mtcars))
summary(lm(mpg ~ wt_s * am_f2 * vs_f2, data=mtcars))
summary(lm(mpg ~ wt_s * am_f1 * vs_f2, data=mtcars))
```

Comment: It seems to me that your treatments are TRUE/FALSE switches.Assuming you have standardized the treatment variables, the interpretation of the interaction coefficient is not straightforward anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standardizing dichotomous variables is not a good idea. By definition, a dichotomous variable is categorical, and the levels (true/false, yes/no, pass/fail) have no quantitative meaning. They can often represented in code as binary - 0 or 1 (although other schemes are possible such as -1/1) but this does not mean that these numbers have a meaning. So standardizing them is meaningless. The only case I can think of where it might be warranted is certain algorithms that require all variables to have the same mean and variance such as penalized methods, eg the Lasso. However, while doing this might aid in the performance of the algorithm, it complicates the interpretation. For standard multivariate regression, it makes no sense at all.

So the answer is to code them as factors. When fitting a regression model, the design matrix is typically constructed using a binary coding for dichotomous factors, so you will get the same result if you treat the variable as binary instead.

As to the 2nd question: The reference level for factors is arbitrary and is based on default rules of the software used to fit the model. Changing the reference level only changes the parametrization of the model. Obviously the individual p-values change because the estimates represent contrasts between the relevant level and the reference level, so if the reference level changes, the estimates and their p-values will change. However the overall model statistics will be unchanged.

Comment: but how do you interprete the interactions of a continous variable with factor variable?

Comment: @colonus in the same way that you would interpret any other interaction. It means that the slope of the continuous variable is different for one or more levels of the categorical variable, and the interaction is the difference in slopes. Remember that the main effect for a variable that is interacted with another variable is the association of that variable with the outcome when the other variable is 0 - in the case of a factor that would be the reference level, assuming they are coded 0/1 - in the case of a continuous variable, if zero is not meaningful then it should be centered first.

Comment: ok. But the continous variable should be centered, right? Otherwise, if the continous variable is not centered there are possible problems with multicolinearity, which would mean that the product of the continous and the factor variable would be highly correlated with the original continous variable.

Comment: @colonus multicollinearity is not usually a problem unless it is near-perfect collinearity, so the zeros in the factor variable would prevent this, but as I said in my last comment, centering the variable is a good idea anyway, and you won't lose anything by doing so..